# Order By if Order ID Exists in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, sql-order-by

I have a table with name and order id, how can i order if only row has order id...

[MY TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvIOh.png)

Here is my code that i have tried:

```
 $this->db->order_by("IF(ISNULL(order_id), '', order_id)", "ASC", false);
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$this->db->order_by("IF(ISNULL(order_id), ondemand.id, order_id)", "ASC", false);
```

Using This code data getting ordered first basis of order id then id, all are ordering by ASC...
But I have to order first basis of order id that's ASC, then id that is DESC...

How can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: `ORDER BY order_id IS NULL ASC/DESC, order_id ASC/DESC`

Comment: how can i use this code in Codeigniter?

Comment: I don't know Codeigniter (except the fact that it exists). Does it have no raw SQL expressions usage?